# I want to pipe an output to multiple files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, suse, tee

I looked up how to do it but don't understand how to use `tee`. It is a little confusing because I am using an output from `awk`. Here is what I have so far: (keep in mind that I am a beginner)

```
num1=2
num2=4

awk 'if (/'$num1'/ == /'$num2'/) 
     {
         print "Hello"
     } 
     else  
     {
         print "Goodbye" 

     }' | tee file1.txt file2.txt
```

I don't know why the output from `awk` is not being printed in the text files.

Comment: Do you get any output if you remove the pipe to tee?

Comment: @AndyLester Yes but I can only redirect the output to file1.txt. Nothing is outputted into file2.txt

Comment: Awk isn't producing output because you didn't give it any input. What is the intent of your script wrt where it gets it's input from? Never do what you are doing here with those awk variables, it is highly susceptible to insidious errors. Use `-v` by default, see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk -v name=value` option to pass shell variables to awk:

```
num1=2
num2=4
awk -v n1=$num1 -v n2=$num2 'BEGIN {if (n1 == n2) print "hello"; else print "Goodbye"}' 
 | tee file1.txt
```

To redirect output from `awk` itself:

```
awk -v n1=$num1 -v n2=$num2 'BEGIN {
    if (n1 == n2) print "hello"; else print "Goodbye"}' > output.txt
```

Comment: I also want the output to go to file2.txt. I tried that with your solution and it is not working.

Comment: Your awk command is just writing `Goodbye` in output, is it how you want?

Comment: Yes because it is a test. I am working on something similar so if this works, then the problem I have will be resovled

Comment: Yes and it would work but the output is only stored into file1.txt and not file2.txt

Comment: Yes because I wrote only `tee file1.txt`. You can use `tee file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: I don't want there to be any output in the terminal. How do you modify the code so that the `awk` will only print in the files and not on the terminal?

Comment: `tee file1.txt file2.txt >/dev/null`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman OR if you don't want output in 2 files see my update to answer.

Comment: @Nosscire, you can also get awk to print to 2 files, but that's too much code to present in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Your awk command has syntax errors. @anubhava has given you a fix for that.

To demonstrate `tee`, let's do something simpler:

```
$ date | tee file1.txt file2.txt
Thu Jun 12 10:44:26 EDT 2014
$ cat file1.txt
Thu Jun 12 10:44:26 EDT 2014
$ cat file2.txt
Thu Jun 12 10:44:26 EDT 2014
```

To conclude: your invocation of `tee` is fine. Your output files do not contain any text because your `awk` program is only printing it's error messages to stderr and nothing to stdout. If you want **all** of awk's output to go into the files, redirect awk's stderr to stdout:

```
awk '...' 2>&1 | tee ...
```

I'll leave that explanation as an exercise

Answer (score 0):

Piping output to `tee` will write the output to the file you indicate and write the output to stdout. Thus, if you want to write the output to multiple files, you can just pipe to another `tee` like so:

```
bbbco $ echo "hello world" | tee /tmp/helloworld1.txt | tee /tmp/helloworld2.txt
hello world

bbbco $ cat /tmp/helloworld1.txt 
hello world

bbbco $ cat /tmp/helloworld2.txt 
hello world
```